# Drawing on Canvas created with Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Right now I'm playing around with JavaFX and what I want to do, is to draw some kind of an animation on a canvas already created with Scene Builder. Unfortunately I can't get anything on the canvas whatsoever since I'm getting some exceptions anytime I do something with the GraphicsContext.

I'm quite new to both Java as well as JavaFX and I've been searching a lot to solve this problem, but I just can't sort it out.

The loop seems to be successfully running as I'm able to obtain the control prints, but anything related to rendering graphics on the `gameCanvas` Canvas triggers the Exceptions.

**The errors:** (I get them for example due to `gc.setFill(Color.RED)` in the `run()` method.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.lambda$0(Game.java:54)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.visitKeyFrame(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.playTo(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.animation.Timeline.doPlayTo(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.animation.AnimationAccessorImpl.playTo(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.InfiniteClipEnvelope.timePulse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.animation.Animation.doTimePulse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.animation.Animation$1.lambda$timePulse$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.animation.Animation$1.timePulse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**My code:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

public class Game implements Initializable, Runnable, ControlledScreen {

    @FXML
    public Canvas gameCanvas;
    private GraphicsContext gc;
    public enum difficulties {EASY, MEDIUM, HARD};

    difficulties difficultyLevel;
    int score = 0;
    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    boolean running = true;
    private Timeline gameloop = new Timeline();

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage) {

    }

    public void setLevelEasy() {
        difficultyLevel = difficulties.EASY;
    }

    public void setLevelMedium() {
        difficultyLevel = difficulties.MEDIUM;
    }

    public void setLevelHard() {
        difficultyLevel = difficulties.HARD;
    }

    @Override

    public void run() { 

        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), event -> {
            if (!running)
                return;
            System.out.println("The loop's running, yai!");

            gc.setFill(Color.RED);

        });

        gameloop.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        gameloop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        gameloop.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        gc = gameCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you calling `run()` from? It doesn't seem to make sense to make the controller implement `Runnable` here.

Comment: @James_D It's called from another class, right after a new Game object is instantiated.

Comment: So are you sure `run()` is being invoked on the actual controller, and on the FX Application thread?

Comment: @James_D Yes, Game class is a controller but I don't really get the second part. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: "Game class is a controller" doesn't really make sense. A controller is a *specific object* (typically created by the `FXMLLoader`), not a class. The `@FXML`-annotated fields are only initialized in the relevant controller. I asked about threads because usually you implement `Runnable` with the intention of executing the `run()` method on a background thread. The code you have in `run()` has to be executed on the FX Application thread, not on a background thread.